# How to parse string key/value and make a new key/value out of it and load it in same map?

Tags: java, dictionary

I have a map of string and string in which I have key/value pair as shown below. For each `client_123`, I will have two keys with their values as shown below.

```
test_client_123=7|0.1|0.2|0.3|0.3
test_abc_pqr_client_123=16|5.5562501|5.1999998|13.6000004|13.6000004

test_client_987=9|0.3|0.4|0.7|0.7
test_abc_pqr_client_987=10|2.222|3.333|4.567|7.876
```

This is just an example, I will have many more key/value pairs in same format. Only difference will be `client_123` will be some other clients like `client_543` and after `=` numbers might be different in pipe as well. That's all.

What does each value mean in pipe delimited format: Here 7 is count, 0.1 is average in ms, 0.2 is Median in ms, 0.3 is 95th percentile in ms and 0.3 again is 99th percentile in ms. Similarly for second line as well. And it will be in this format always.

**Problem Statement:**

For this line `test_client_123=7|0.1|0.2|0.3|0.3`, I need to make below new key/value pair and load it in same map:

```
test_in_process_client_123_count=7
test_in_process_client_123_avg_in_ms=0.1
test_in_process_client_123_median_in_ms=0.2
test_in_process_client_123_95_in_ms=0.3
test_in_process_client_123_99_in_ms=0.3
```

And similarly for this line `test_abc_pqr_client_123=16|5.5562501|5.1999998|13.6000004|13.6000004`, I want to make below new key/value pair and load it in same map:

```
test_abc_pqr_client_123_count=16
test_abc_pqr_client_123_avg_in_ms=5.5562501
test_abc_pqr_client_123_median_in_ms=5.1999998
test_abc_pqr_client_123_95_in_ms=13.6000004
test_abc_pqr_client_123_99_in_ms=13.6000004
```

How can I achieve this? Below is the code where I load all original key/value pairs in a map:

```
String response = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);
Matcher m = PATTERN.matcher(response);
while (m.find()) {
    metricHolder.put(m.group(1), m.group(2));
}
```

Now this `metricHolder` map will have above original key and pipe delimited values. Now I want to load new key/value pair in the same `metricHolder` map and also remove original key/value pair from the map as well after we convert them to new key/value pair.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting problem to solve, I came out with my own solution for this, hope it helps you or it is useful for what you are trying to do, if I understand well you want to add new records to your map, based on the previous entries, then this is what I did:

```
public class DictionaryProcessor {

//Suffixes and common String parts
final static String PROCESS = "_in_process_";
final static String COUNT = "_count";
final static String AVG_IN_MS = "_avg_in_ms";
final static String MEDIAN_IN_MS = "_median_in_ms";
final static String N95_IN_MS = "_95_in_ms";
final static String N99_IN_MS = "_99_in_ms";
final static String PQR = "_pqr_";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Assuming this is the data you have:
    Map<String, String> dictionaryMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    dictionaryMap.put("test_client_123", "7|0.1|0.2|0.3|0.3");
    dictionaryMap.put("test_abc_pqr_client_123", "16|5.5562501|5.1999998|13.6000004|13.6000004");
    dictionaryMap.put("test_client_987", "9|0.3|0.4|0.7|0.7");
    dictionaryMap.put("test_abc_pqr_client_987", "10|2.222|3.333|4.567|7.876");

    //I will define a temporary map to hold the new values
    Map<String, String> tempMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    //We will iterate our map 
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : dictionaryMap.entrySet()) {

        String currentKey = entry.getKey();//Get the current key
        String currentValue = entry.getValue();//Get the current value for the key
        //Since the value has the data separated by "|", I'd like to use "StringTokenizer" (Split or regex are worth to use to)
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(currentValue, "|");

        String count = tokenizer.nextToken().trim();
        String avgData = tokenizer.nextToken().trim();
        String medianData = tokenizer.nextToken().trim();
        String n95data = tokenizer.nextToken().trim();
        String n99data = tokenizer.nextToken().trim();

        tempMap.put(generateNewKey(currentKey, currentKey.contains(PQR), COUNT), count);
        tempMap.put(generateNewKey(currentKey, currentKey.contains(PQR), AVG_IN_MS), avgData);
        tempMap.put(generateNewKey(currentKey, currentKey.contains(PQR), MEDIAN_IN_MS), medianData);
        tempMap.put(generateNewKey(currentKey, currentKey.contains(PQR), N95_IN_MS), n95data);
        tempMap.put(generateNewKey(currentKey, currentKey.contains(PQR), N99_IN_MS), n99data);
    }

    //Iterate the temporary map and add it to the existing dictionary map
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : tempMap.entrySet()) {
        dictionaryMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }

    printMap(dictionaryMap);

}

private static void printMap(Map<String, String> targetMap) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : targetMap.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "=" + entry.getValue());
    }
}

private static String generateNewKey(String currentKey, boolean hasPQR,
        String constant) {
    StringBuilder newKey = new StringBuilder();

    if (hasPQR) {
        newKey.append(currentKey).append(constant);
    } else {
        String firstPart = currentKey.substring(0, currentKey.indexOf("_"));
        String secondPart = currentKey.substring(currentKey.lastIndexOf("_") + 1, currentKey.length());
        newKey.append(firstPart).append(PROCESS).append(secondPart).append(constant);
    }

    return newKey.toString();
}

}
```

Hope it is useful. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your problem correctly, you have to parse out the value entries in the current map using "|" (pipe) as the delimiter and then put back each individual parsed value as key value pair. Some thing like this code below:

```
  String test_client_123="7|0.1|0.2|0.3|0.3" ;
  Map<String, String> the_map = new HashMap<String, String>() ;

  the_map.clear() ;
  String[] values = test_client_123.split("\\|");
  for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      if (i == 0)
         the_map.put("count", values[i]);
      else if (i == 1)
         the_map.put("avg_in_ms", values[i]);
      else if (i == 2)
         the_map.put("med_in_ms", values[i]);
      else if (i == 3)
         the_map.put("95_in_ms", values[i]);
      else if (i == 4)
         the_map.put("99_in_ms", values[i]);
  }
```

Hope it helps ...

Comment: In this case a `switch-case` looks more suitable.

Comment: Actually you understood few things. My new key is not count, avg_in_ms my new key is before equal sign and value is after equal sign.